# PHP_Calculation_Exception - maybe related to Excel Version in German

Tags: php, exception, phpexcel

I am using a German Excel Version and wrote following formula into Cell AM27:

```
=WENNFEHLER(AN61/(AN$61+AN$62+AN$63);"")
```

This correspondends to the English formular:

```
=iferror(AM61/(AM$61+AM$62+AM$63),"")
```

Now I am loading and saving the file with PHPExcel and get this exception:

```
PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception: MySheetName!AN27 -> Formula Error: Unexpected ,
```

My questions are

1. Does the same error happen when one uses an English Excel Version and the English formular?
2. Is there a way how I can solve this exception?
3. Or can I work on other parts of the sheetand save the file without calculating this cell?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Section 4.6.4 of the developer documentation:

When writing a formula to a cell:

- Decimal separator is `.` (period)
- Function argument separator is `,` (comma)
- Matrix row separator is `;` (semicolon)
- English function names must be used

e.g.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue(
        'AM27',
        '=IFERROR(AM61/(AM$61+AM$62+AM$63),"")'
    );
```

If you want to write formulae using German language function names and separators, you need to use the locale functions to handle translation between German and English (as described in section 4.6.5 of the developer documentation):

```
$locale = 'de';
$validLocale = PHPExcel_Settings::setLocale($locale);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue(
        'AM27',
        PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()
            ->translateFormulaToEnglish(
                '=WENNFEHLER(AM61/(AM$61+AM$62+AM$63);"")'
            )
    );
```

Comment: Hi Mark,

Thanks for the fast answer. Maybe I did not make myself clear enough: I **did not** write any formular with PHPExcel. I am trying to work with an workbook that already contains formulars. 
I load the workbook with PHPExcel, then I save it with PHPExcel - I am not doing anything in between(!)
During the saving there is the above exception.

Comment: What format is the file that you are reading? Excel2007 OfficeOpenXML holds formulae internally as text in English/American format, while Excel5 (BIFF) uses a tokenised format that is converted to an English/American text format by the Excel5 reader. If the file is a CSV file with the formula rendered as formulae rather than as calculated values, then this translation will need to be done manually because PHPExcel won't then convert for you.

Comment: Hi Mark,
it seems we ar eone step further:
The file actually was Excel5 so this could be the reason.

However, now I manually saved the file as Excel2007 and retried the procedure. I am getting an error which looks like an infinite loop with this error message:

Notice: Undefined index:  in D:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\u116003\Eigene Datei
en\Programmier Bereich\lib\PHPExcel\Calculation\LookupRef.php on l
ine 629
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 33 in D:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\u116003\Eigene Dateien\Programmier Bereich\lib\PHPExcel\Calculation\LookupRef.
php on line 622

Can you help me?

Comment: Another note:
I could avoid the previous error by skipping a sheet with alot of formulars. This just let me run into the next problem from a sheet with many pictures in it:

PHPExcel_Writer_Exception: File zip://D:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\u116003\Eig
ene Dateien\Programmier Bereich\DTO Reporting\test\fixture\ScoreCard\tmpOutputTe
mplate.xlsx#xl/media/image1.png does not exist

Again: when I removed the pictures from that sheet I could load and save the file.

Ofcause it would be nice to be able to save the file with the formulars and the pictures :-)